# Insert rows and columns of zeros between every row column

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

If i have a MxN matrix, how do i add(not replace) a row of zeros and a column of zeros after every other column/row in the original matrix in matlab?
Effectively the result would be 2Mx2N.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in the following way. Do not add the new rows and columns but create an empty matrix and fill the elements from the original matrix.

Create a new matrix with the dimensions `2Mx2N`

```
 B = zeros(2*size(A));
```

(assuming that `A` is your original matrix). Using

```
 B(1:2:end,1:2:end) = A;
```

should result in the correct new matrix.